# Clojure: llegalArgumentException in a Clojure recur - type mismatch

Tags: clojure

The following is a simplified example of a loop/recur construct that is intended to work with `byte`s.

```
(defn test-lr []
  (loop [last-byte (byte 0)
         bytez (map byte '(1 2 3 4))
         answer '()]
    (if (empty? bytez)
      answer
      (recur (first bytez)
             (rest bytez)
             (cons (bit-or (first bytez last-byte) answer))))))
```

Whenever I attempt to compile this code in a REPL, I receive the following error.

```
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
recur arg for primitive local: last_byte is not matching primitive,
had: Object, needed: byte, compiling:...
```

The error suggests there's a type mismatch between what the `loop` bindings are expecting and what the call to `recur` is providing with its first argument. They both seem to be `byte`s, so I don't see what the problem is.

```
user=> (type (byte 0))
java.lang.Byte
user=> (type (first (map byte '(1 2 3))))
java.lang.Byte
```

Answer (score 2):

I asked about this on the Clojure IRC channel, and users amalloy and dbasch helped me out. My understanding from that conversation follows.

It seems the problem is that the binding for `last-byte` in the `loop` bindings is a Java primitive `byte`, whereas `(first bytez)` is actually returning a `java.lang.Byte`, which is derived from `java.lang.Object`. As a result, there is a type mismatch between the expected `byte` Java primitive, and the `java.lang.Byte` (derived from `Object`) that is passed in the call to `recur`: hence the error message.

A workaround is to cast the `recur` argument to a primitive: `(byte (first bytez))`.

Another option is to work with a `byte-array` and use `aget` for access.

In general it's important to be aware of the types you're working with, and keep in mind that primitives and boxed types aren't necessarily interchangeable. It also seems that Clojure functions don't generally (ever?) return Java primitives.